# Define sorting key on Django model

Tags: python, django, sorting

I have two Django models, in which the one refers to the other. I want to be able to sort the second model based on the first. I think the code example below illustrates best what I want to achieve.

```
class Record(models.Model):
    uuid = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=32)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['code']

class Article(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=32)

    def get_sorted_submodels(self):
        return sorted(self.submodels.all(), key=Submodel.key_sorting)

class Submodel(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, related_name='submodels')
    record_uuid = models.CharField(max_length=32)

    @property
    def record(self):
        return Record.objects.get(uuid=self.record_uuid)

    @staticmethod
    def key_sorting(obj):
        return (obj.record, obj.code)
```

If I now call the method `get_sorted_submodels`, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: unorderable types: Record() < Record()
```

I already implemented the field ordering on model Record.

1. How can I make this model orderable such that I can use this sorting
   mechanism?
2. If that is not possible, is there another good way to
   enable sorting on Record first, and then on its own code?

PS: I explicitly do not want to use `class Meta` and `ordering` on Submodel class, since this is basically a second ordering only used in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ordering` Meta field only controls how records are sorted *in database queries*. `sorted` is a Python function and completely unrelated to this.

To make `Record` instance sortable in Python, you can give them a `__lt__` method:

```
def __lt__(self, other):
    return self.code < other.code
```

Now Python can sort them, and your error will be gone. But it's better to let the database do it, so don't use `sorted` at all:

```
def get_sorted_submodels(self):
    return self.submodels.order_by('record__code')
```

Edit: to do it after your edit, I'd change the methods like so (import cached_property from django.utils.decorators):

```
@cached_property
def record(self):
    return Record.objects.get(uuid=self.record_uuid)

@staticmethod
def key_sorting(obj):
    return (obj.record.code, obj.code)
```

Comment: I like this answer. However, I see that I simplified my example too much. I edit my question with a slightly more complicated example that I have.

Comment: I see. If it's not actually a foreign key but you do it by hand, then you can't use the database. Now your key_sorting function will have to retrieve the Records. But you can replace \@property with @cached_property to save some queries.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to use this ordering in some contexts you can specify it wherever you select your records. This should work: `Submodel.objects.all().order_by('submodels', 'record__name')`.

If you need to use this custom ordering in a lot of different places you can look into making a custom Model Manager.